# Kivy on Windows10. How to click a button, when kivy application does not in focus?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a simple kivy app with 3 buttons. When my kivy app is not in focus, I have to click on it once, in order to press any button. How can I click any button with only one click without activating a kivy window?

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
```

cannot press any button, when a window is not in focus

[image]

Comment: I think that is a Window issue. Do you see the same behavior for other applications (not Kivy)?

Comment: @John For example, I can press any button in Google Chrome or in Visual Studio without focus on them.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue recently as well. Couldn't find a solution but I did implement a workaround that worked. What I did was bound `kivy.core.window.Window` to `on_cursor_enter` to trigger a callback that brings the kivy app to foreground, gaining focus, whenever the mouse enters back into the kivy app window:

```
Window.bind(on_cursor_enter=mouseEnter)

def mouseEnter(instance):
    Window.raise_window()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by Jack's answer. I have found that `Window.raise_window` causes the taskbar icon to start flashing (at least on Windows 10), so I would recommend using `Window.show` instead. This seems to work just the same, but does not make the taskbar icon flash.

**Full code:**

```
Window.bind(on_cursor_enter=lambda *__: Window.show())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following at the top of your code:

```
import os
os.environ["SDL_MOUSE_FOCUS_CLICKTHROUGH"] = '1'
```

See discussion at:
https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users/c/b1wXKpjzjkg/m/5HF6WxSyAwAJ